# Aligning an enumeration item to the top of a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I've drawn a tree using pgf/tikz and am trying to place it in an enumerated list. A snippet of my complete code is as follows:

```
\subsection*{Problem 2}
\begin{enumerate}[1)]
\item Max heap
\item
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}]
\node [circle,draw] (z){98}
  child {node [circle,draw] (a) {80}
    child {node [circle,draw] (b) {23}
      child {node [circle,draw] (c) {18}}
      child {node [circle,draw] (d) {21}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] (g) {48}}
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] (j) {79}
    child {node [circle,draw] (k) {76}}
    child {node [circle,draw] (l) {29}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
```

My problem is the list number is aligned with the bottom of the tikzpicture. How would I go about aligning it with the top of the tikzpicture?

Comment: A complete (compilable) minimal example would be better. For example until now it's not clear which of the packages `enumerate` and `enumitem` has been used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
\item \leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: +1 for this answer since, if anything else, it's a perfectly useful and acceptable solution for all parts of the question posed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/positioning-of-numbers-in-gb4e-sty-examples (for which I also answered, only in a rather different way, and for which I *really* wish I'd seen your answer here first -- it would have saved me very much time `:)` ).

Comment: The problem with this is that the number can wind up on a separate page from the tree.  Matthew's solution solves that.

Answer (score 15):

Just add `baseline`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1},baseline]
```

without any arguments, `baseline` takes the value `0pt`, which is great because your tree grows downwards.  So y=0 is at the top.

Answer (score 10):

You have to determine explicitly the base line of the `tikzpicture` environment with respect to the current line. See sample below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Max heap
    \item
      \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline=(current bounding box.north),
        level/.style={sibling distance=50mm/#1}
      ]
        \node [circle,draw] (z){98}
        child {node [circle,draw] (a) {80}
          child {node [circle,draw] (b) {23}
            child {node [circle,draw] (c) {18}}
            child {node [circle,draw] (d) {21}}
          }
          child {node [circle,draw] (g) {48}}
        }
        child {node [circle,draw] (j) {79}
          child {node [circle,draw] (k) {76}}
            child {node [circle,draw] (l) {29}}
        };
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even better is `baseline={($(current bounding box.north)-(0,1.6ex)$)}` as it aligns the top of the picture with the top of the line. (Don’t forget to add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.)

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to bring the number up (and this is what I always do) is to simply add `~\\` after `\item`.

Comment: Nice, but why does this work?