# Vertical alignment of tikzpicture with text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have some text, and a corresponding `tikzpicture`, both of which are to be part of a test question, and which are thus included as part of an `\item` in an enumerate environment.

Like this:

```
\item 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}  
    description of question  
\end{minipage}  
\hspace*{1cm}  
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.35\linewidth}  
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]  
    question diagram  
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{minipage}
```

What I want is for the text to be vertically aligned as it would be without a `minipage` environment, and for the top of the `tikzpicture` to be aligned with the top of the text.

I can obtain this alignment with the option "`baseline=4cm`" in `tikzpicture`, but this has the result of putting in a large amount of vertical white space before the item, which then has to be countered with `\vspace*{-2cm}`.

Is there a better, automatic, way rather than fiddling with vertical space?

Comment: Hi Alasdair, you can use `\`` to format inline code and package/environment names. Code listings needs to be indented with 4 spaces to get syntax highlighted. You can use `101010` button on top of the edit window to do this automatically.

Comment: it would be great if you would post a small compilable example with a real TikZ diagram showing what you mean and which we could test.

Comment: The answers to [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5023/aligning-an-enumeration-item-to-the-top-of-a-tikzpicture) might be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a generic trick, to add a `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning of the `minipage` environment. For example:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}  
\vspace{0pt}
    description of question  
\end{minipage}  
\hspace*{1cm}  
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}  
\vspace{0pt}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me for some quite different problem with a badly aligned graphic in a minipage as well.

Comment: Does anybody know why this trick is working?