# Dancing images in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, overlays

When creating a slide using pauses and \only, I am getting cases where the content shifts between slides. I have tried using overlayarea and overprint as described in [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer) (in every combination I could think of - in one or the other or both columns, around the whole thing, using \only, using \onslide), but I still get dancing images.

Minimal example follows. Note, while debugging I am including the same image 5 times, but in our end document I will be using 5 different images (all the same size). [ **Update:** The dancing seems to happen on the slide where the visible portion of the itemize environment exceeds the height of the image, so this may depend on the image size ]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Riverbend Community Math Center}
\begin{columns}[c]
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Founded in Summer of 2006
    \item Centered in St.~Joseph County, Indiana
    \item Independent, non-profit organization
    \item Serves people ages 5 through adult
    \item Promotes interest and confidence in mathematics
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    \only<1>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<3>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<4>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<5>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For complete information, I am using XeLaTeX but see the same dancing when compiling with plain LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the center alignment of the two columns (because you use `{columns}[c]`). I would change that to top alignment (`[t]`) and add `\vspace{0cm}` on top of the second column to create a narrow top line to which the first line of the first column is aligned to. This is basically the same solution as for [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages/11631#11631) and [Vertical alignment of tikzpicture with text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11533/vertical-alignment-of-tikzpicture-with-text/11564#11564) just for beamer columns.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Riverbend Community Math Center}
\begin{columns}[t]
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Founded in Summer of 2006
    \item Centered in St.~Joseph County, Indiana
    \item Independent, non-profit organization
    \item Serves people ages 5 through adult
    \item Promotes interest and confidence in mathematics
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    \vspace{0cm}
    \only<1>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<3>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<4>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<5>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that instead `\only<n>{\includegraphics[...]{...}}` you can also write `\includegraphics<n>[...]{...}` which should have the same effect, but is shorter.

Comment: * Thanks for the \includegraphics<n> comment - that one was not on the list of "temporalable" commands that I saw.

Comment: Oddly enough, using \includegraphics<n> is sufficient to solve the problem! There must be some magic there.

Comment: @Dean: It might be the spaces caused by the line breaks after `\only<n>{...}`! Always add a `%` when the line ends with `}` in such cases.

Comment: @Dean: Indeed! The spaces after `\only<n>{...}` are causing the "dancing". Simply write `\only<n>{...}%` instead or use `\includegraphics<n>...` which includes a trailing `\ignorespaces` (in the redefined form of `beamer`).

Comment: Trailing `%`: Oh how terribly silly, yes, I know that issue and should have thought of it. Adding trailing `%` to the `\only` lines is also sufficient to fix the original code. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Dean: Don't worry, this happened to me as well for `\only{}`. There is is kind of difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Try an `overlayarea` environment like this:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Riverbend Community Math Center}
\begin{columns}[c]
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Founded in Summer of 2006
    \item Centered in St.~Joseph County, Indiana
    \item Independent, non-profit organization
    \item Serves people ages 5 through adult
    \item Promotes interest and confidence in mathematics
    \end{itemize}
    \end{overlayarea}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}
    \only<1>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<3>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<4>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \only<5>{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RiverbendCommunityMathCenter}}
    \end{overlayarea}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This breaks vertical centering of the second column.