# Align \item labels at top of mdframed box

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate, enumitem, mdframed

By default, `enumerate`'s `\item` labels align with the top of the text:

[image]

However, if the text happens to be a `mdframed` box, the labels align with the **bottom** of the box which does not look so good:

[image]

### Question:

How do I align the labels at the top for both the framed and non-framed case?

---

### Failed Solution:

I attempted to use the `adjustbox` package as per [Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/aligning-enumerate-labels-to-top-of-image):

```
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
        \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{\TextBFramed}
        \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{\TextCFramed}
    \end{enumerate}
```

but this yields the following error:

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

---

### Almost Working (Manual) Solution:

Adapting [this solution from Aligning an enumeration item to the top of a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6485/4301) seems to work, but how do I automate this without redefining `\item`.  Also, the label is not quite aligned with the baseline of the first line in the frame (which can be tweaked by changing the `2`, but how do I determine this value in different situations).

```
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
        \item ~\\[-2\baselineskip] \TextBFramed
        \item ~\\[-2\baselineskip] \TextCFramed
    \end{enumerate}
```

[image]

I'd be ok with replacing `\item` with `\MyItem`, so something like:

```
\newcommand{\MyItem}{\item ~\\[-2\baselineskip]}%
```

but I would need this `\MyItem` to only apply the `~\\[-2\baselineskip]`, when the content is an `mdframed` box, but not otherwise.  Also, how do I determine the value of the multiplier? See the **Mixed text (failed automated solution)** section below.

---

### Notes:

- Since redefining `\item` can be dangerous in [strange interaction between `mdframed` and `\item`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47397/strange-interaction-between-mdframed-and-item), I am trying to avoid that by using `\MyItem`.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=30cm]{geometry}% fit on "one" page
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\TextB}{%
        Duis blandit tempus placerat. 
        Nulla vitae erat ante. Nulla facilisi. 
        Aliquam tristique interdum suscipit. 
        Duis posuere orci vel velit suscipit in porttitor purus eleifend. 
}%
\newcommand{\TextBFramed}{%
    \begin{mdframed}%
        \TextB%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\newcommand{\TextC}{%
    \begin{align*}
        e &= mc^2\\
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
}%
\newcommand{\TextCFramed}{%
    \begin{mdframed}%
        \TextC%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%


\begin{document}\noindent
\textbf{Plain text (works fine):}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \item \TextB
    \item \TextC
\end{enumerate}
%
\medskip\noindent
\textbf{Framed text (not so good):}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \item \TextBFramed
    \item \TextCFramed
\end{enumerate}
%
\medskip\noindent
\textbf{Using adjustbox yields error:}
%\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
%   \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{\TextBFramed}
%   \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{\TextCFramed}
%\end{enumerate}

\medskip\noindent
\textbf{Framed text (manual solution):}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \item ~\\[-2\baselineskip] \TextBFramed
    \item ~\\[-2\baselineskip] \TextCFramed
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip\noindent
\newcommand{\MyItem}{\item ~\\[-2\baselineskip]}%
\textbf{Mixed text (failed automated solution):}\medskip
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \MyItem \TextB
    \MyItem \TextC
    \MyItem \TextBFramed
    \MyItem \TextCFramed
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `mdframed` is done by a simple `makebox`. At the moment I have no better idea ;-).

Whatever. To align the complete environment at the top you can modify the output with a vtop:

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@makebox@out[2][\linewidth]{%
 \noindent\hb@xt@\z@{%
    \noindent\makebox[\dimexpr #1\relax][l]{\vtop{\vskip-\ht\strutbox\vskip-\dp\strutbox\relax#2}}%
 \hss}%
}%
\makeatother
```

The complete code results to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=30cm]{geometry}% fit on "one" page
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@makebox@out[2][\linewidth]{%
 \noindent\hb@xt@\z@{%
    \noindent\makebox[\dimexpr #1\relax][l]{\vtop{\vskip-\ht\strutbox\vskip-\dp\strutbox\relax#2}}%
 \hss}%
}%
\makeatother


\newcommand{\TextB}{%
        Duis blandit tempus placerat. 
        Nulla vitae erat ante. Nulla facilisi. 
        Aliquam tristique interdum suscipit. 
        Duis posuere orci vel velit suscipit in porttitor purus eleifend. 
}%
\newcommand{\TextBFramed}{%
    \begin{mdframed}%
        \TextB%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\newcommand{\TextC}{%
    \begin{align*}
        e &= mc^2\\
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
}%
\newcommand{\TextCFramed}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[skipabove=0pt]%
        \TextC%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%


\begin{document}
\textbf{Framed text (not so good):}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \item \TextBFramed
    \item \TextCFramed
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```