# mdframed in two column book vertical alignment problem (first page only)

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column, mdframed

I am trying to align the columns of the first page but without success into the `mdframed`. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn,twoside]{book}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
linecolor=red,linewidth=0pt,%
leftmargin = 0 ,%
rightmargin =0 ,%
frametitlerule=true,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow,%
innertopmargin=\topskip,%
innerleftmargin=1,%
innerrightmargin=1,%
middlelinewidth=0,% 
skipabove=0 ,%
skipbelow =0,%
outermargin=0,%
}

\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{axiom}{Axiom}

\begin{document}
\begin{axiom}[lala]
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{axiom}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see [`Marco Daniel's answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58339/3954) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56439/3954. Adding the code that starts with `\makeatletter` and ends with `\makeatother` to your preamble, solves the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I can't test now, but can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I tested by adding the patch from the linked question _after_ `\usepackage{mdframed}` and seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you @GonzaloMedina, and all although the bottom needs attention now.